# Как оставить определенные символы в текстовом файле питон

Tags: python

Есть папка со множеством папок и файлов, среди которых есть файлы txt. В этих файлах нужно оставить только определенные символы, определенные символы заменить на слова (например @ на собака) и удалить двойные пробелы.
Вот, что написал для перебора файлов

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя!\'\"(),-.:;? '

names = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for name in names:
    fullname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name)
    if os.path.isfile(fullname) and Path(fullname).suffix == '.txt':
        with open(fullname) as f:
            s = f.read()
```

Собственно, после этого нужно преобразовать строку s. Полагаю, для всего этого можно использовать регулярные выражения, но не могу понять как именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_replacer():
    import re

    allowed = '''-a-z а-яё!'"(),.:;?'''
    # тире важно оставить в самом начале (или в конце),
    # т.к. посередине он воспринимается как спецсимвол для regex[...]

    replace_table = {
        '@': 'собака'
    }

    ###
    regex = r'[^' + allowed.replace(']', r'\]') + ']'

    replacer = lambda match_obj: replace_table.get(match_obj.group(0), '')

    def main_replacer(string):
        string = re.sub(r'\s\s+', '', string)
        return re.sub(regex, replacer, string, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

    return main_replacer

###
replace = create_replacer()

string = '@ и еще @?:%№;%№      \n\n\n x'

print( replace(string) ) # собака и еще собака?:;x
```

`[^перечисленое]` — такое выражение одначает «всё, кроме перечисленных символов в квадратных скобках»

Исходную строку взял в три кавычки, чтобы не париться с экранированием кавычек.

`'\s\s+'`: `\s` — любой пробельный символ (space), включая переносы строки. `+` — один или много раз подряд. Удалит всё пробельное, что встретится 2 или больше раз подряд.

`main_replacer` первым шагом удаляет все пробелы, вторым шагом производит удаление / замену всех лишних символов, для каждого совпадения вызывая функцию `replacer`, которая в виде первого аргумента получает объект совпадения.

`match_obj.group(0)` — совпавшая строка используется как ключ словаря. Если для него есть подготовленная замена - вернется она, иначе - `''` по умолчанию.

P.s. комменатрий вначале кода надо бы оставить, чтобы не забыть про потенциальный источник бага. Или в начальной строке перечислить весь алфавит, а экранирование `\-` предусмотреть в коде.